# Need to Access Chrome Keystore from a website

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, mobile-website, android-keystore

I need to access the android keystore of the chrome mobile app when i open my site on the app. Is it possible? If yes, how can we do it ?

Comment: [tag:trusted-web-activity] might help support this?

Comment: TWA is used to open browser in your application, but i want to open my site in chrome app and access its android features. Is this possible ?